# How to open application in netBeans IDE 7.0.1 in full screen mode?

Tags: java, netbeans, size, jframe

Hej all,

I would like to open my application in netBeans in the fullscreen mode when running it.

I have tried many things. Lastly, I have tried to put following code to the "Customize code" option when clicked on PrefferedSize in the properties of the main JFrame:

```
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

Unfortunately, it doesnt work. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By "fullscreen" do you mean "maximized"?  If so, then try this:

```
myFrame.setExtendedState(myFrame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

You don't say what OS you're using, but if you're using Windows and you find your taskbar is covered by the maximized frame call this beforehand:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
myFrame.setMaximizedBounds(env.getMaximumWindowBounds());
```